# Is the language of turing machines, which return epsilon on its own encoding, decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

Is the language $\{ \langle M\rangle | f(\langle M\rangle)=\epsilon\}$ decidable? $f()$ means, that the turing machine returns $\epsilon$ on its own encoding and $\langle M\rangle$ stands for the encoding (a "string-version" of the TM).

I have no idea how I should start. How can I decide, if I use a reduction, a sub program technique or the diagonalizability? I would really appreciate if you could help me, thanks! :)

Comment: Hint: Given a Turing Machine $M$ you can always define a turning Machine $M'$ that ignores its input, simulates $M$ on the empty input, and when $M$ halts (possibly never), returns $\epsilon$.

Comment: "$f()$ means, that the turing machine..." What Turing machine? Do you mean $M(\langle M\rangle)$?